# AngularJS Routing with multiple URL attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

In my application I need to use some routes where it takes multiple attributes from the URL so I can pass them in PHP.

I currently have this which works:

```
.when('/jobs/:type', {
        templateUrl: function(attrs){ return '/pages/jobs.php?_type=' + attrs.type; },
        controller  : 'jobsController'
    })
```

Which lets me access `_type` with a `$_GET` in jobs.php.

I am trying to work it out so I can have mutiple `attrs` in my template Url? Here's an example:

```
.when('/page/:data1/:data2', {
        templateUrl: function(attrs){ return '/pages/page.php?data1=' + attrs.data1 + '&data2=' + attrs.data2; },
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })
```

Which just breaks my application. I'm sure there's a simple way to do this I just cannot seem to figure it out because I'm newish to Javascript and Angular.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was merely a mistake on my end calling the wrong file.

```
.when('/page/:data1/:data2', {
    templateUrl: function(attrs){ return '/pages/page.php?data1=' + attrs.data1 + '&data2=' + attrs.data2; },
    controller  : 'mainController'
})
```

Does work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to assign php file as templateUrl. This way I don't think you will be able to use angularjs features on your php file. Its better to call your php file through service and manipulate your data using angular on front-end. One possible way to do this can be

ROUTER

```
.when('/page/:data1/:data2', {
    templateUrl: views/page.html,
    controller  : 'mainController'
})
```

CONTROLLER

```
app.module('myApp').controller('mainController', function(pageService, $scope){
  var init = function(){
  var data1 = '1234';
  var data2 = '4567';
 pageService.getPageData(data1, data2)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
             //
             })
}
init();
})
```

SERVICE

```
app.module('myApp').controller('pageService', function($http){
    var factory = {};

    factory.getPageDetails(data1, data2){
        return $http({
            url: '/pages/page.php?data1=' + data1 + '&data2=' + data2;,
            method: 'GET'
        });
    }
return factory;
});
```

Comment: My php file I'm calling is just a template file, I can still angular features inside of it.